# Clutch drops to the floor when I start to apply the brakes

Tags: ford, brakes, clutch, escort

Why does my clutch drop to the floor of my 93 ford escort as soon as I start to apply pressure on my brakes. I already changed out my master cylinder and bled the brakes. Could it have anything to do with my brake booster?

Comment: Although this had been flagged as too broad I believe this question is answerable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would cause a clutch master cylinder to go bad?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/14624/what-would-cause-a-clutch-master-cylinder-to-go-bad)

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem on the same vehicle. after changing all of the hard brake lines, like other vehicles it can be very, very difficult to bleed the brakes, especially after replacing components.

I don't like this answer, but I simply needed to bleed and re-bleed until whatever air bubbles in the system were flushed out.
Must have passed 2 quarts of fluid through.

That said do not dismiss tightening the new connections you had made...